# error creating ssl context () qt

Tags: c++, qt, парсер, mediawiki

Пытаюсь запустить простой пример парсинга с Википедии, но он выдаёт ошибку :

```
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_new
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
Network Error:
 "Error creating SSL context ()"
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
Response Received:
 ""
```

Использую Windows 8 и mingw32-make.
Пробовал искать библиотеки : 
LIBS += -libeay32
LIBS += -ssleay32
и подключать. Качал [тут](https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/). Но всё равно не работает.

Сам пример:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QSslError>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication application(argc, argv);
    QNetworkAccessManager qnam;
    const QNetworkRequest wikireq(QUrl(QStringLiteral("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&titles=lemon")));
    QNetworkReply* wikirep = qnam.get(wikireq);
    QObject::connect(wikirep,&QNetworkReply::finished,[wikirep]()->void{
        QTextStream repStream(wikirep);
        qDebug() << "Response Received:\n" << repStream.readAll();
        wikirep->deleteLater();
    });
    QObject::connect(wikirep,QOverload<QNetworkReply::NetworkError>::of(&QNetworkReply::error),[wikirep]()->void{
        qDebug() << "Network Error:\n" << wikirep->errorString();
        wikirep->deleteLater();
    });
    QObject::connect(wikirep,&QNetworkReply::sslErrors,[wikirep](const QList<QSslError> &errors)->void{
        qDebug() << "SSL Errors:";
        for(auto&& err : errors)
            qDebug() << err.errorString();
        wikirep->deleteLater();
    });
    return application.exec();
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894056/error-creating-ssl-context-qt

Comment: @Unick Это не помогло , к тому же я не использую MSVC ++

Comment: может вам стоит указать ОС, копилятор тогда в вопросе.

Comment: @Unick Да сейчас

Answer (score 1):

Мне помогла [ссылка](http://codeblog.vurdalakov.net/2009/11/solution-qsslsocket-cannot-call.html). Я просто установил, что там требуется и добавил в pro файл две библиотеки из папки bin установленного приложения.

```
LIBS += -Llibeay32 -Lssleay32
```